# ¿Cómo hacer un makefile que calcule las dependencias?

Tags: c++, makefile

En el proyecto que me han asignado utilizan un conjunto de makefiles muy primitivo en que cada objeto .o depende solo del .cpp a partir del que se genera.
Lo cual nos obliga a hacer un `make clean` cada vez que tenemos que compilar algo con la consiguiente pérdida de tiempo pues tarda un par de minutos en compilar todo.

Simplificándolo a lo esencial del problema, el makefile con el que trabajo es este :

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall
INCLUDES =

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

.cpp.o :
        $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

OBJETOS =\
        a.o\
        b.o\

%.o : %.cpp
        $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(@F) -c $<

ejecutable: $(OBJETOS)
        $(CPP) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJETOS) -o ejecutable

all : ejecutable

clean :
        -rm -f *.o
        -rm -f ejecutable
```

Y los ficheros .cpp y .h serían los siguientes :

```
// Fichero a.h
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_
#endif  // _A_H_

// Fichero b.h
#ifndef _B_H_
#define _B_H_
#endif  // _B_H_

// Fichero comun.h
#include "comun.h"
#ifndef _COMUN_H_
#define _COMUN_H_
#endif  // _COMUN_H_

// Fichero a.cpp
#include "a.h"

// Fichero b.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

Es fácil ver que con el makefile anterior un cambio en a.h no provocaría una recompilación al hacer `make`, motivo por el que tenemos que hacer 'make clean' antes.

Hacer un makefile correcto para el ejemplo anterior es fácil :

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall
INCLUDES = 

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

.cpp.o :
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

OBJETOS =\
    a.o\
    b.o\

ejecutable: $(OBJETOS)
    $(CPP) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJETOS) -o ejecutable

a.o : a.cpp a.h comun.h
b.o : b.cpp a.h b.h comun.h

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(@F) -c $<

all : ejecutable

clean :
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f ejecutable
```

Pero este makefile mejorado tiene dos problemas :

- En el proyecto real hay cientos de archivos y escribir a mano las dependencias sería muy costoso.
- Aunque las escribiese a mano. Cada vez que se modifique un archivo para añadir o quitar un `#include` hay que modificar el makefile.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el makefile calcule las dependencias cada vez?

Comment: ¿quieres una solución independiente del compilador o te alcanza con que funcione con g++?

Comment: Me es suficiente una que funcione con g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tiene que cambiar el Makefile un poco para añadir la generacion de las dependencias para cada fichero, como se indica [aquí](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html) (en inglés). gcc (y g++ por tanto) generará todas las dependencias de un .c o .cpp usando la opción `-MM`:

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall
INCLUDES = 

OBJETOS =\
    a.o\
    b.o\

DEPS = $(OBJETOS:.o=.dep)


.SUFFIXES: .cpp .dep

all : ejecutable

# añadir la informacion de las dependencias para .o archivos existentes
include $(DEPS)


%.dep : %.cpp
    $(CPP) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< > $@

# ¿las dos reglas iguales?
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<


#.cpp.o :
#        $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

ejecutable: $(OBJETOS)
    $(CPP) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJETOS) -o ejecutable

clean :
    -rm -f $(OBJETOS) $(DEPS)
    -rm -f ejecutable
```

Puede verificarse así:

```
> make clean
rm -f a.o b.o  a.dep b.dep
rm -f ejecutable
>  make   
Makefile:17: a.dep: No such file or directory
Makefile:17: b.dep: No such file or directory
g++ -MM -fPIC -Wall  b.cpp > b.dep
g++ -MM -fPIC -Wall  a.cpp > a.dep
g++ -fPIC -Wall  -o a.o -c a.cpp
g++ -fPIC -Wall  -o b.o -c b.cpp
g++  a.o b.o  -o ejecutable
>  make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>  touch a.h
>  make
g++ -fPIC -Wall  -o a.o -c a.cpp
g++ -fPIC -Wall  -o b.o -c b.cpp
g++  a.o b.o  -o ejecutable
>  touch b.h   
>  make
g++ -fPIC -Wall  -o b.o -c b.cpp
g++  a.o b.o  -o ejecutable
> _
```

Comment: Funciona bien, gracias y +1. Tiene el pequeño inconveniente de que si hago dos veces `make clean` en el segundo crea los .dep para despues borrarlos.